# How to add values to a new column after n rows?

Tags: numpy

I have this loop that continuously checks api data and add it to an array. 
Then I calculate an indicator based on one column of the array that I want to add the the array. The issue only is that the indicator need 10 data point to get going.

```
import numpy as np

list_b = []
i = 0

while True:
    i += 1
    list_a = [] 

    list_a.append(i)
    list_a.append(33)
    list_a.append(44)
    list_b.append(list_a)
    array = np.array(list_b, dtype=float)

    if len(array) > 10:
        x = indicator_function(array[:,0])
        np.append(x) # in a 4th column

    if i == 15:
        break

print(array.shape)
print(len(array))
print(array)
```

The issue is that I cant append to the array because it doesnt have the same dimensions as the array before. So how can I extend the array by one column or insert the new indicators values in a new column after 10 rows.

The array should be formed like this:

```
1 33 44
2 33 44
...
9 33 44
10 33 44
11 33 44 x
12 33 44 x
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, numpy doesn't allow for jagged arrays (arrays with a changing number of columns). You might have to create an entirely new array. Or, if you want to do something crazy, you could move the `if` statement up above `list_b.append(list_a)` and change it to

```
if (i > 10):
    x = indicator_function(array[:,0])
    list_a.append(x)
else:
    list_a.append(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if i < 10:   
    list_a.append(i)
    list_a.append(33)
    list_a.append(44)
    list_a.append(55)
    list_b.append(list_a)
    array = np.array(list_b, dtype=float)

if i > 10:
    list_a.append(i)
    list_a.append(33)
    list_a.append(44)
    list_a.append(66)
    list_b.append(list_a)
    array = np.array(list_b, dtype=float)
```

@sahil yes that works.

Answer (score 0):

There's no builtin support for proper jagged arrays in numpy. The best bet for your application is probably a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#the-numpy-ma-module):

```
import itertools
import numpy.ma as ma

array = None
list_b = []

def indicator_function(arr):
    return -1

for i in itertools.count():
    list_a = []
    list_b.append(list_a)

    list_a.append(i)
    list_a.append(33)
    list_a.append(44)
    list_a.append(np.nan)
    array = ma.MaskedArray(list_b)

    # assign mask or indicator_function, as appropriate
    ix = 10 + 1
    array[:ix, -1] = ma.masked
    array[ix:, -1] = indicator_function(array[:,0])

    if i == 15:
        break
```

This results in a masked `array` that looks like:

```
[[0.0, 33.0, 44.0, --],
 [1.0, 33.0, 44.0, --],
 [2.0, 33.0, 44.0, --],
 [3.0, 33.0, 44.0, --],
 [4.0, 33.0, 44.0, --],
 [5.0, 33.0, 44.0, --],
 [6.0, 33.0, 44.0, --],
 [7.0, 33.0, 44.0, --],
 [8.0, 33.0, 44.0, --],
 [9.0, 33.0, 44.0, --],
 [10.0, 33.0, 44.0, --],
 [11.0, 33.0, 44.0, -1.0],
 [12.0, 33.0, 44.0, -1.0],
 [13.0, 33.0, 44.0, -1.0],
 [14.0, 33.0, 44.0, -1.0],
 [15.0, 33.0, 44.0, -1.0]]
```